# Getting blank page after Facebook share or cancel

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a facebook share using the feed method, all work fine when I am using a browser.

But when it comes to using an web application with Phonegap(WebView), and when I press "cancel" or "share"(Shared properly to facebook) I always get redirected to a blank page with the following url
https://m.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/feed

Any thoughts?

```
            var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            display: 'touch',
            link: url,
            picture: image,
            name: title,
            description: description,
            redirect_uri:"http://someurl"
        };
        function callback(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                window.location.href ="http://someurl"
                console.log("Facebook share has been made!");
            } else {
                console.log("Facebook not shared!");
            }
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Comment: My guess is that FB is trying to close the window, and it's unable to do so because you're on a webview. I would also consider using Graph API directly, the only drawback being you have to go through Facebook Application Review and implement Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the blank screen on Android Webview by using the following URL:

```
  window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&amp;display=popup&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer"
```

Replace the redirect_uri accordingly.